# Spring Batch Processing using Spring Cloud data flow

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have spring batch app and I want an admin portal to manage failed jobs and see other job related activities. I saw there was some Spring batch Admin portal package in spring, but it has been deprecated in 2017 and I have to use Spring cloud data flow as mentioned [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch-admin/trunk/). I want to know for Spring cloud data flow, is this some dependency we need to add to project as an artifact or is this some separate standalone service that needs to be set up?

My batch has dozen of cron jobs, can I just give my jar to Cloud Data Flow and it will take care of rest or Do I need to configure each and every job there? Any sample for the same are appreciated, as I want to know how big will be an effort to set up all this.

On the side note : My app is a combination of some REST controllers and some batch jobs.So does it make sense to use cloud data flow? If not, then is there better console manager for batch jobs(like restart ,cancel jobs portal) etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data Flow requires a server to be running, where you can deploy your jars (register tasks as wrapper over spring batch). This server will be responsible for orchestration and deploying to runtime. If you have massive work load you probably need to go with cluster and Kubernetes, which supports scheduling via cron, but if now you have a single server that handles all together and you don't have performance issues, you may simplify it by using Local mode. But with Local mode you have to manage scheduling anyway by yourself with Quartz for example. 
https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/feature-guides/batch/scheduling/

So just having SCDF for monitoring may be complicated and probably requires re-think your application design. Also SCDF as I see is good when you have some dependencies between tasks. 
Maybe it would be easier for you to write couple of REST endpoint to fetch failed jobs and re-run them - everything depends on what you need and how big your app is.

PS:
I'm currently also thinking between having just spring batch monolith or cloud ready tasks :)